# typeorm QueryBuilder: how to match column value of boolean?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

In Typeorm Query Builder, what is the syntax like when I want to match rows whose value is equal to a boolean of True?

For example, I have this working code:

```
  await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .delete()
      .from(Notification)
      .where("id = :id", { id: 1 })
      .andWhere('dstOrgId = :dstOrgId', { dstOrgId: 1001 })
      .execute();
```

However, if I want to match all rows whose `clicked` column has a value of boolean `True`, how should I write it?

I want to do something like:

```
  await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .delete()
      .from(Notification)
      .where("clicked = :x", { x: true })
      .andWhere("viewed = :x", { x: false })
      .execute();
```

But this above code does not seem to be in nice syntax, or "proper" syntax

Answer (score 0):

this should help all

Needs use @Column property "transformer"

this suggestion has been shared by typeorm team

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3875
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3942

Answer (score 0):

Solution=>

```
await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .delete()
      .from(Notification)
      .where("clicked = :clicked", { clicked: true })
      .andWhere('viewed = :viewed', { viewed: false })
      .execute();
```

TypeORM documentation reference =>

```
const user = await createQueryBuilder("user")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.photos", "photo")
    .where("user.name = :name", { name: "Timber" })
    .andWhere("photo.isRemoved = :isRemoved", { isRemoved: false })
    .getOne()
```

So, basically your solution is in correct format!